# How to create a UIView withouth blocking the UI

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How can I create lots of `UIView` & setting text on the `UITextView` which is the subview of UIView in Background thread.

Currently I am using a `for loop` to create the `UIView` but it is blocking the user to do anything.

Please help me to get this done.
Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: ..run in background thread?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242307/how-to-update-a-ui-label-from-a-non-ui-thread-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

`UIKit` is not intended to be used in background. You do not need to have lots and lots of instantiated `UIViews`, as they would consume a lot of resources, but as many as you can show on the screen, then just reuse them for showing the others, eg. when the users scrolls. That's the idea of the collection views and table views - use them instead or implement your own reusable mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do all your UI changes in the main thread. You can create `UIView` in background mode, but call `addSubview`: method in main thread.

( Thanks Minerva )

Comment: So you are saying that i cant add a subview to UiView in background mode

Comment: You can do it. But it can cause unexpected result.

Comment: No you can't, you also can't use initWithFrame: as it's not thread safe, neither adding the text field. Results are unexpected.

Comment: Thanks @graver & Gago for the help